# unique wildcard update SQL syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, wildcard

I'm incredibly new to SQL (as in I've been painfully teaching myself "database administration" for a couple weeks at my job...) and I'm in a bit of a pickle.  I have a table that has a column full of zip codes, but the data that was imported to this database was incorrect and we have a large, large number of zip codes with four digits versus five (the leading 0 was omitted).

I managed to get a script working that replaces a known four digit zip code with a proper five digit zip code, but the problem there is we have a few hundred thousand entries and I can't realistically thumb through them all to find every entry with four digits and add the zero.

I've copied the database and have ruined it a few times trying to make some syntax work, but essentially I am looking for a quick fix to simply add a 0 to any FOUR digit zip code while leaving any FIVE digit zip code alone.

Is there a way that I can simply have a SQL script use a wildcard for whatever the four digits are and add a zero at the start?  I messed around for 45~ minutes at this place (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) trying to get something to work to no avail.

Much, much appreciation to anyone able to assist.

Pertinent information:

- Table: tbl_Address
- Column:  ReceiverPostalCode
- Incorrect Postal Codes:  8481 (should be 08481), 8638 (should be 08638), etc
- Correct Postal Codes: 20872, 27501, 90039, etc

Best,
Steve

Comment: Just some quick advice if you're new to working in databases. You may want to get into the habit of running an update or delete as a select first (to see what you would be updating), and backing up your data before you run any big updates.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Dan!  I'll be sure to Google those terms you recommended and incorporate them into my practices.  I have the backups (I think, haha...) taken care of already.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no zips are longer than 5 characters, you can do this:

```
update tbl_Address
set ReceiverPostalCode = right(concat('00', ReceiverPostalCode ), 5) 
where len(ReceiverPostalCode) between 3 and 4
```

Comment: This looks right in my opinion.  The only danger you have is accuracy of the zip codes.  So I'd run those through a service to ensure the addresses are proper (i.e., Melissa Data). +1

Comment: `right(concat('0000', ReceiverPostalCode ), 5)` would be more general.

Comment: Is there a method in which I can check to verify no zip codes exceed five characters?  I manually scanned 2500 records and didn't see anything, but I imagine there is a strong possibility that at least a zip code from Canada is involved and adding a 0 to the beginning of that would be bad.

Comment: @user3224945 Canadian postal codes should be 6 characters I believe (+1 if storing the middle space), so I think you may be safe, but it's good to check. If you run `select max(len(ReceiverPostalCode)) from tbl_Address` it should return the longest value. You could do something like: `select len(ReceiverPostalCode), count(*) from tbl_Address group by len(ReceiverPostalCode) order by 1 DESC` to see how many records by length exist. If a length seemed odd, you could then `select * from tbl_Address where len(ReceiverPostalCode) = ...` to see those records specifically.

Comment: Okay, you are correct - six is the longest field so we should be good to go.  I checked and we have 116 records at 6, a bunch at 5, and about 5000 that are incorrect (4 digits).  We apparently have 16 that are 3 (which I think means it should have two 00s?) and 34 as NULL (those can remain NULL...).  Do I use Gordon or RedFilter's example, though?  And is there a simple way to include those 16 entries that are missing two 0s?

Comment: @NorthernBeard I updated my query to work for your specific data.

Comment: @RedFilter You are a rockstar!  Thank you VERY much for your help, and thank you to everyone else who assisted as well!  The SQL script provided by RedFIlter worked and we are good to go...database is working as expected prior to the issue.